# Передача указателей в функцию

Tags: c

Как правильно передать в функцию указатель?

Вот так он был объявлен в `main()`:

```
struct Node* z=NULL;
char* forstr = NULL;
```

А это передача адреса указателя в функцию:

```
sortstation(&forstr,stringout,stringin6,&z);
```

Прототип функции выглядит вот так:

```
void sortstation(char**, char*,char*,struct Node**);
```

А сама шапка функции вот так:

```
void sortstation(char** forstr, char* stringout, char* stringin6, struct Node** z)
```

Как же всё-таки правильно передавать в функцию указатели?

Comment: Указатель на указатель то же не работает

Comment: Как минимум , компилятор принял такую запись char** forstr , struct Node** z , но *z->Data ,не работает

Comment: Вы с прототипом функции не ошиблись? Он по числу и типу параметров не совпадает с "шапкой".

Comment: Один я ничего не понел?.. Вы в функцию передаете 2 параметра, прототип имеет 3, а  шапка 4 аргумента

Comment: @zed,Исправил , можете посмотреть ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если прототип функции такой:

```
void sortstation(char**, char*, char*, struct Node **);
```

то вызывать её надо вот так:

```
sortstation(&forstr, stringout, stringin6, &z);
```

Перед вызовом важно убедиться, что выделена память под `forstr` и `z`:

```
z = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
forstr = malloc(...);
```

Comment: ,а оригинальные значения при этом будут меняться ?

Comment: @Elvin Обновил ответ.